# Android & Maps v2: how do I get the users location?

Tags: android, android-maps

I have a lot to do before I am finished, after 8 hours straight working on this I need to ask for help. I have managed to set up V2 maps on Android they work on my device, I do not know where to find a resource that could help me build this up to a more advanced map application, I cannot even get the users location to show. I am debugging on an Android phone which has the internet. I have read more than 10 questions on Stack overflow as well as read through some of the documentation on Google.

Here is my class so far:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {


  private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     setUpMapIfNeeded();

}

  @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }



  private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }


  private void setUpMap() {

      mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
      mMap.getMyLocation();



    }
}
```

I need to build up to getting the users location, then allowing the user to search for places and store them, does anyone think this would be possible in V2 maps?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I need to build up to getting the users location, then allowing the user to search for places and store them, does anyone think this would be possible in V2 maps?

You would need to find the user's location via `LocationManager`, as you would in any Android app. Optionally, you can feed those locations to Maps V2 via calling `setLocationSource()` on your `GoogleMap`.

**UPDATE**

If you use `setMyLocationEnabled(true)` on `GoogleMap`, you can retrieve a location via `getMyLocation()` on `GoogleMap`. This is simpler than rolling your own location tracking, but you do not get as much control (e.g., you are not informed of movement).

Comment: I have tried to do as you suggested but I am missing something, if you have the time could you show me how this can be done? I keep finding geopoints which I think are now deprecated? Thank you!

Comment: @deucalion0: See this sample project: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Location

Comment: Thanks for your help, I spent like an hour and a half going through all your code, its too much for me to get my head around, I gave up but I am back to trying again, I wont let this beat me! :) I will have a look at your updated answer. You see my issue is that I just want to see each part done a bit at a time, too much code gets me messed up :) Thank you!

Comment: @deucalion0: Well, there are other sample projects in that same `MapsV2/` directory in my repo, some of which are simpler, though that one is the only one that works with the location stuff. And, FWIW, the book chapter covering all those samples should be out late next week.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare I appreciate your help! I cant wait for the book! I will continue to look through your repo! :)

Comment: @CommonsWare...you says, "If you use setMyLocationEnabled(true) on GoogleMap, you can retrieve a location via getMyLocation() on GoogleMap.". How can you retrieve a location via getMyLocation() on Google Map ? Is it possible to do so without using Location Manager or Location Listener? If available, please let me know HOW TO. p.s. I tested your sample code linked above from your github, but I could not find it.

Comment: @BBonDoo: "How can you retrieve a location via getMyLocation() on Google Map ?" -- `getMyLocation()` is a method on the `GoogleMap` class. You can call this method to retrieve the `Location`. "I could not find it" -- my sample does not show `getMyLocation()`. The comment where I linked to that sample project was posted before the update to the answer that mentioned `getMyLocation()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare..Thanks in advance..I know getMyLocation() method and what I want to know is, how use that method on the state of setMyLocationEnabled(true) without implementing Location Manager and Location Listener ? please show me the sample code in the seperate text window.

Answer (score 1):

Today I received an e-mail from Google Maps, which is referred to get the current location on the new Google Maps API v2,

Since last month, many developers, including me, have found a problem  or inconvenience of getting the current location on new Google Maps API v2.

That problem is

> " Use a GoogleMap and enable my location using
>   setMyLocationEnabled(true). There is no way (I mean no proper way as
>   there is no callbacks) to be notified of a location change using the
>   default/built-in LocationSource. There should be a way to be notified
>   of a change in the user/my location. API v1 had a way to do it. No
>   having it requires building a complex algorithm that may not be in
>   sync with what the GoogleMap is currently displaying."

The above question is linked at here. http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4644

Then today Google maps team sent an e-mail to many developers:

> "This issue will be fixed in the next release of the Maps Android
>   API."

That's it all..

Answer (score 1):

And it has.  See the Location API for Google Maps V2.
http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html